# jQuery getting jQuery to find the closest class selector for Image Switcher

Tags: jquery

Just wondering if anyone can help me out, guide me in the right direction on some jQuery? Still quite new to it. I'm trying to use classes as I want to use multiple instances of the same image switcher on the one page but currently if you click one it changes on all. How do I write my jQuery so it finds the closest class and only executes on that instance. CodePen below. Thanks

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XBVwpg

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.thumbs img').click(function(){ 
    $('.largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
  });

});
```

Comment: *«finds the closest class»* of what? Your CodePen seems to be working...

Comment: There's two image switchers in that codepen. Clicking a thumbnail on one updates both. I'm looking for a way to have it so that if you click on a thumbnail it updates the closest large image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement it like this, but this will not work if you change the html of your page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.thumbs img').click(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $parent = $this.parent('.thumbs');
    $previous = $parent.prev();
    $previous.attr('src',$this.attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mjKGPb

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed :)